# MigratorDotNet for Plugins Architecture

Tags: fluent-migrator, migratordotnet, migrator.net

We're starting to use Migrator.NET for managing our database migrations, its fantastic but we have an additional requirement that plug-ins written for our software which require their own custom fields added (depending on the plug in of course).

So basically we have a our core database tables, and our plugin specific tables.

I was hoping that in Migrator.NET I would see some sort of additional attribute like this

```
[Migration(1, "Core")
public class Migration1 : Migration
{
}
```

so that I'd be able to then plug in developers would then be able to do something like

```
[Migration(1, "PluginName")
public class Migration1 : Migration
{
}
```

Unfortunately this parameter doesn't exist, and the version table doesn't seem to have any place to store a tag/plugin name

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VersionInfo](
    [Version] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AppliedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Does anybody have any ideas how I would go about doing this?

I've seen that Ruby/Redmine support this sort of architecture as they allow plugins to include their own db migrations, however would love to be able to do this in MigratorDotNet.

Comment: Ok I've discovered RikMigrations has support for a "Module"

[assembly: Migration(typeof(M001_Update), 1, "ModuleName"]

only problem is it doesn't support MySql! and the project seems pretty st ale compared to FluentMigrations. Anyway with a module name plugin developers can simply specify their plug in name as a module so I'm almost there. Anyone have a solution for MySql?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you're tagging, and you can filter migrations based on Tags, like so:

```
[Tags("DK", "NL", "UK")]
[Tags("Staging", "Production")]
[Migration(1)]
public class DoSomeStuffToEuropeanStagingAndProdDbs() { }
```

See the following wiki page for more details:

https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Filter-migrations-run-based-on-Tags